# Plone CMS - unable to publish page

Tags: plone

We are using a Plone CMS system with already published site. When I create a new page, all of a sudden I'm not able to publish it. I tried duplicating a published page to see if that would get published but I receive the same error when I try to make it live.

Below is the full error message:
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ZMSoK5UU1PuFjAc8FdckjUcqo6XoIN3nfEHG5zfaltI

Any idea what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the full *text* of the tracebacks in this post. The crucial parts from these are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message: quintagroup.plonegooglesitemaps is failing in an attempt to ping Google, probably to let it know about the publication. I'd try disabling that add on.